# What's the most innovative/easiest IDE for learning html5/php/mysql/etc

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, ide

15 years ago I did all my development in notepad, it was slow, confusing and it took me years before I could make something production ready. I haven't written anything in so long I've forgotten virtually everything, except how many thousands of hours it took me to learn through trial and error the last time. I don't have the time to do it all over again but I want to build some web apps

Are there any IDE's that have come out recently that make learning to develop for the web easier? There must be something out there more advanced than notepad, or Dreamweaver these days... I've seen kickstarters promising similar years ago (can't recall the software though).

Comment: Eh, you'll get a 10 different answers from 10 people with that question. I use [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and I'm very pleased with it. Best IDE I've ever worked with.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime text is one of the most commonly used code editors. It supports most languages and offers syntax highlighting, and code completion as well as a view of your directory. I want to say that Sublime is leading the pack in terms of popularity.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest https://code.visualstudio.com/ (Visual Studio code).
It's open-source ,cross-platform . it has several built-in snippets .One of the key features is its great debugging support in node.js applications(JavaScript and TypeScript).You can also manage your Git .
Definetely worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) provides a solution for every popular language out there. Best part for me is, you learn one and you know them all since it essentially has the same functionality between different editors. I am currently using phpStorm, webStorm and Clion and I am extremely satisfied.

Comment: Looks pretty good, I prefer open sourced but I'll download the trial and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Atom](https://atom.io/). It's a text editor with loads of auto complete. Not to mention it will try to parse and understand your entire project directory and provide auto complete based on it if possible. I can only suggest, try everything and see which one suite yourself.

Although it is possible to use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) to code in HTML5/JS, just pick the EE package.

Comment: Atom seems interesting, pretty rapid development.  Any problems with performance though?

Comment: i can't think any, although in system that unable to handle tons of process, atom can be a real pain. it uses separate process for different task - plugin, interface, parsing. As for Netbeans, it might become a memory hog once you open three or more large project.